# Displaying PSW content

Tags: masm, x86-16, masm32

I'm beginner with asm, so I've been researching for my question for a while but answears were unsatisfactory. I'm wondering how to display PSW content on standard output. Other thing, how to display Instruction Pointer value ? I would be very gratefull if ypu could give me a hint (or better a scratch of code). It may be masm or 8086 as well (actually I don't know  wthat is the difference :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction pointer is not directly accessible on the x86 family, however, it is quite straightforward to retrieve its value - it will never be accurate though.
Since a subroutine call places the return address on the stack, you just need to copy it from there and violá! You have the address of the opcode following the `call` instruction:

```
proc getInstructionPointer
    push bp
    mov bp,sp

    mov ax,[word ptr ss:bp + 2]

    mov sp,bp
    pop bp
    ret
endp getInstructionPointer
```

The PSW on the x86 is called the Flags register. There are two operations that explicitly reference it: `pushf` and `popf`. As you might have guessed, you can simply push the Flags onto the stack and load it to any general purpose register you like:

```
pushf
pop ax
```

Displaying these values consists of converting their values to ASCII and writing them onto the screen. There are several ways of doing this - search for "string output assembly", I bet you find the answer.

To dispel a minor confusion: 8086 is the CPU itself, whereas MASM is the assembler. The syntax is assembler-specific; MASM assembly is x86 assembly. TASM assembly is x86 assembly as well, just like NASM assembly.
When one says "x86 Assembly", he/she is referencing any of these (or others), talking about the instruction set, not the dialect.

*Note that the above examples are 16bit, indtended for 8086 and won't work on 80386+ in 32bit mode*